# C# Marshalling vs Serialization

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization, marshalling

I have a C# app which read/write messages of some predefined protocol from/to USB.  So I have at least 2 options here. One is serialize/Deserialize. The other is marshal. At the beginning I was picking the first option and it worked fine. But after more and more message types are introduced I am annoyed by the cumbersome implementation for each message type and feel the marshal may be a better way to go. I haven't use marshal before. Is it the right way to go? I did some test. One problem I have is when I have a structure with an array, how to write to it? Such as the following:-

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=TotalBytesInStruct),Serializable]
    public struct SomeData
    {
        /// char[15]
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 15)]
        public sbyte[] data;

        /// int[15]
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)]
        public int[] prob;
    }
```

It appears that the data and prob are both reference and I have to new a object to use them, which sounds not quite right to me. I need the whole struct to be a continuous block of memory, which I don't think the new operator will do that for me.

Any suggestion is really appreciated

The following is how I did by serialization.

```
    List<byte> rawData = new List<byte>();
    rawData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(ProtocolVersion));
    // 16 bytes for operator ID
    byte[] temp = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(OperatorId), temp, OperatorId.Length > temp.Length ? temp.Length : OperatorId.Length);
    rawData.AddRange(temp);

    // 16 bytes for operator password
    Array.Clear(temp, 0, temp.Length);
    Array.Copy(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(OperatorPassword), temp, OperatorPassword.Length > temp.Length ? temp.Length : OperatorPassword.Length);
    rawData.AddRange(temp);
```

The following is how I did by marshaling

```
    static byte[] RawSerialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
        byte[] result = new byte[size];
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, buffer, false);
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, result, 0, size);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: There are ways to serialize and deserialize in a generic way, with very little ceremony.  Can you show us how you are doing it?

Comment: Also, if you could tell us a little more about why serialization is not working for you, and why you think marshaling might be better, that would be great.

Comment: I have add the code sample. I didn't say it don't work me. Just because i have to parse message for different types.

Comment: The marshaling example looks pretty good.  That's essentially how I do in in the program I'm currently writing.  So what is your doubt?

Comment: I'm not family with Marshaling and the unsafe code make me nervous, although I'm a C++ programmer. In the later part of my post, I said I have some problem with accessing an array.

Comment: At the beginning, I was trying to do things like 'someData.data[0] = 10'. Then the compiler told me the 'data' is a null reference. Than I did 'data = new sbyte[15]' which passed the compilation. But I need the whole struct in a continuous block of memory. The 'new' thing looks not right to me.

Comment: You need to be really specific about what your question is that you want us to answer.  There's nothing we can do about it "not looking right;" focus on what behavior you want, why you think your code is not achieving the correct behavior, and how we can help you improve the code so that it produces the behavior you want.

Comment: Ok, if I did "someData.data = new sbytes[15]", what Marshal.Copy will do? Copy the contents of the array to the byte array or just the reference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I only need to new an array like the following and it works fine.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class SomeData
{
    /// char[15]
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)]
    public byte[] data = new byte[15];

    /// int[15]
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)]
    public int[] prob = new int[15];
}
```